# What is the formula to predict a high probability of range 0~9, given by past results?

Tags: probability

I'm very new and i'm below average for my math.

But there's this thing about a lucky draw game that bugs me to think of a probability.

Say the host of a party has already drawn several luck draw numbers for each 2 hours, such as below:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Time} & \text{1st Draw} & \text{2nd Draw} & \text{3rd Draw}\\ 
\hline
\\08 AM & 1516 & 4865 & 9876
\\10 AM & 0513 & 7805 & 9843
\\12 PM & 1124 & 0350 & 8790
\\02 PM & 9802 & 7967 & 3210
\\04 PM & 8794 & 6350 & 7842
\\06 PM & ???? & ???? & ????
\end{array}$$

Now, at $06:00 PM$ I would like to find out the [????].
I wish to know from the range of [0~9], what will be the 4 digits highly probable number to appear.
It does not need to be sorted in any order.
e.g, if you think the result is $0531$, then it doesn't matter if its $0351$ or $5130$ or $3150$ or etc...
It does not need to be in any specific draws, meaning dont care if its [1st draw] or [3rd draw]...
All I need to know is the 4 high probability digits.


Any ideas? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are those draws some of 10000 cards that are drawn and will never be drawn again?

If not and they are just drawn sets of digits that are allowed to repeat and are not dependent on each other then it's impossible to get the answer that you want. In this case the previous numbers give no information about the following numbers and this is how such lotteries work in real life.

Comment: numbers will repeat.